# Como validar um payload vazio vindo de uma API?

Tags: php, api, laravel-5

Tenho uma API que retorna em erro quando passo o parâmetro do payload como: `{}`. Isso acontece porque ele entra no método, passando pela validação do laravel. A validação da regra está configurada abaixo:

```
 public function rules()
 {
      return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', Rule::in($this->events)],
            'payload' => 'required'
      ]; 
 }
```

Este é um outro método que tentei fazer para validar o payload em caso de erro ou de requisição inválida:

```
private function validatePayloadRequest($data)
    {
        if (isset($data['payload'])) {
            try {
              $request = json_decode($data['payload'], true);
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                $validateDataPayload['status'] = false;
                $validateDataPayload['validate'] = 'The parameters are incorrect or incomplete';
            }

            if ($request !== null && is_array($request) && count($request) && !is_numeric(array_keys($request)[0])) {
              //Estou tentando escapar dessa condição, mas não sei como fazer, ou se há uma maneira mais simples de resolver isso
               $validateDataPayload = $this->request->validPayload($request);
            } else {
                $validateDataPayload['status'] = false;
                $validateDataPayload['validate'] = 'Check the parameters. Are incorrect or incomplete';
            }
        }

        if (!$validateDataPayload['status']) {
            return $validateDataPayload;
        }
        return $request;

    }
```

Sou novo no laravel, então estou tentando entender esses filtros de validação... Existe algum tipo que filtra quando o valor for: `{}`, no php: `Array(0)`.

Teria que retornar algo como isso, porém só ocorre se o parâmetro não for setado:

```
{
    "validate": {
        "payload": [
            "Payload is required."
        ]
    },
    "status": false
}
```

> **Obs**: Eu fiz assim:  `'payload' => 'required|regex:/[^{}]/'`

Funciona, porém quando, eu passo um parâmetro que não corresponde com a validação do payload, o erro persiste, tipo : `{"a": "qualquercoisa"}`, sendo que a chave "a" não existe na minha aplicação... daí ele nem entra na validação secundária dos parâmetros do payload:

```
 public function validPayload($data)
  {
      $rules = [
                'user_id' => 'required|integer',
                'page' => 'required|integer',
                'access_token' => ['required', 'string']
      ];
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual validação quer usar. Sua explicação foi confusa

Comment: Exatamente, @VirgilioNovic, o problema era entender porque a validação não estava processando para os valores do payload inválidos, mas já descobri o problema, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema, a validação já estava funcionando.

O problema estava em outro lugar, que já corrigi. 
Estava passando o `$request` direto para o método getDataUser, então não estava verificando o status... daí nunca entrava na validação.

```
 public function getUsers(Request $r)
 {
     $data = $r->all();

     $validate = $this->request->validate($data);
     /* faltou isso */
     if (!$validate['status']) {
        return $validate;
     }

     $request = $this->validatePayloadRequest($data);
     //dd($request);

     if (!$request['status']) {
        return $request;
     }

     return $this->user->getDataUser($request);
 }
```